# After adding google-play-service_lib my resourceIds cannot be recognized

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, resource-id

I am using ADT 23.0.2.
I just imported the google-play library to my workspace and added the reference to it in my project.

Now nowhere in my project the resource ids can be recognized because there is no R file. 
(Anywhere I have R.id.blah I get the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable);

It's just gone. What am I supposed to do? 
I exactly followed the steps by developers.google.com. It's nothing complicated but I don't know why this happened.

(I have all layout files in place and no import for android.R are in my class files.)

Before adding the 
Tools I use:

[image]

Here are screenshots from my app properties:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My manifest

> ```
> <permission 
>   android:name="com.appname.appname4.MAPS_RECEIVE"
>   android:protectionLevel="signature">
> </permission>
> <uses-permission android:name="com.appname.appname4.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
> ```
>
> ```
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.appname.appname4.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.appname.appname4.SearchResultListActivity"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result_list"
>         android:parentActivityName="com.appname.appname4.MainActivity" >
>         <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>             android:value="com.appname.appname4.MainActivity" />
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.appname.appname4.ContactInfoActivity"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_property_detail"
>         android:parentActivityName="com.appname.appname4.SearchResultListActivity"
> ```
>
> >
>
> ```
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: Yes I have. No change.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when I first started Android programming. Here are some fixes that worked for me in the past.

#### 1. Fix/Check all xml(layout) files.

Many times a R file not being generated is due to an issue with your layout file or Android Manifest file. Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) link and work your way down the page checking permissions and the general layout format.

#### 2. Project/Clean.

go to Project->Clean.
Also make sure you have selected the option to build project [automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50BmL.png).(Without this option check marked R file is never generated automatically).

#### 3. Fix Project Properties.

Right click on your project in Package explorer then choose [fix project properties](https://www.google.com/search?q=fix%20project%20properties%20eclipse&safe=off&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Z17yU_vVDcSIogSrm4LoAQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1019#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=WNEqU4a81fMgzM%253A%3B1d9JcHaPr7NEkM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Flh4.googleusercontent.com%252F6mK7tr5Mbo7zhQ6UFHz6ttyNWbUHIDHJ08ssasfD22BvQ1spUOQRhSvLzi5qaH_DNHT1TfJdhENirSO2X0QyekYI67vnYZei19rx4kcrSb4VWmYoSe9glT6iUw%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.twitter.com%252Fdocs%252Fsimple-ads-demo-android-13-opening-eclipse%3B673%3B876).
Repeat Step 1 after this.

#### 4. Builders.

Go to Project->Properties then [Builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201166/android-r-java-file-not-found). Select the appropriate boxes.
Repeat Step 1, and Clean and rebuild project.

#### 5. Appcom7 and Google Play services error.

Sometimes to fix errors associated with installing these two reference libraries. I copy there folders into a generic library folder on my hard(where I keep most of my eclipse reference libraries), after this I delete them from the Package explorer and from the "default" directory where they were installed. I Fix project properties again and clean/rebuild. This should get you back to your non-reference library version of the package. Then I manually add them as Projects to my eclipse IDE and finally follow [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) to add them as references to my project. Then fix project properties,clean and rebuild.

#### 6. Reference Question.

Finally, referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) StackOverflow page has helped me countless times. And one way or another fixed my issue.

Good Luck.